# Numbers in localized custom font in android

Tags: android, fonts, localization

I am developing an Android application using Bengali Font. As such there is no issue in using Bengali Font for text item. Text are taken from text files and loaded using Bengali Typeface.  But I am not sure how best, I can accommodate numeric figure. For example final scores of Test is presented in a format like:
**Your Score = 50**
Suppose I want to present it in Bengali like:
**আপনার স্কোর  = ৫০**
The problem is numeric figure is calculated at run-time. I thought of keeping a map files containing digit and their localized characters and thus presenting the numbers in custom font. But that is not very efficient way. In Android is there any support for formatting numbers in localized font like Bengali or Tamil?

Answer (score 1):

To use numbers in custom font look at the  Android documentation of  [NumericShaper](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/awt/font/NumericShaper.html).